# Download files in API ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to create an API that downloads a specific file from the server in ASP.Net Core.
I'm Using the ASP.NET Boilerplate.
I've tried every solution i found, and non of them helped me.
most of the solutions I've tried, implements something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)  
  {  
      if (filename == null)  
          return Content("filename not present");  

      var path = Path.Combine(  
                     Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),  
                     "wwwroot", filename);  

      var memory = new MemoryStream();  
      using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))  
      {  
          await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);  
      }  
      memory.Position = 0;  
      return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));  
  }
```

And when using it, I always get an error on the last line `Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method`.

Comment: Try changing the last line to:
```return File(memory.ToArray(), GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));```

Comment: @Vladimir i've tried and nothing changed

Comment: Stop your debugger on the last line, and in the *Immediate window* of Visual Studio enter the command: ```GetContentType(path)```, to see what that method returns

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this error during compilation, it's probably because the compiler thinks you're trying to invoke the constructor on the `System.IO.File` class instead of invoking the `File()` method on the `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` class.

Try to call the method by explicitly scoping it to the instance with `this.File(...)`.